# Using Eloquent ORM in Laravel to perform search of database using LIKE

Tags: orm, laravel, eloquent, sql-like

I want to use Eloquent's active record building to build a search query, but it is going to be a LIKE search. I have found the `User::find($term)` or `User::find(1)`, but this is not generating a like statement. I'm not looking for a direct answer, but if someone could at least give me a direction to look in that'd be great!

Comment: http://laravel.com/docs/database/eloquent .. you can use documentation ıt is very clear.

Comment: I've seen this page I just didn't see anything about searching with wildcards. I also didn't want to set up a regex in a foreach loop as there are hundreds of thousands of rows

Comment: $email = DB::table('users')->where('id', '=', 1)->only('email');

Comment: it is called fluent query builder in the docs.

Comment: If I could mark the answer and your comment as the answer, I would. Thank you for getting me in the right direction

Comment: You're looking for a full-text seach, it's necesary use fluent. You can use this information http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html

Answer (score 244, accepted):

You're able to do database finds using LIKE with this syntax:

```
Model::where('column', 'LIKE', '%value%')->get();
```

Comment: not so efficient, throws "Fatal error: Maximum function nesting level of '100' reached, aborting! in... "

Comment: @gsk I think you join (using the with() method) and then you can search the column as usual. The syntax is probably something like `table.field`.

Answer (score 69):

If you need to frequently use LIKE, you can simplify the problem a bit. A custom method like () can be created in  the model that inherits the Eloquent ORM:

```
public  function scopeLike($query, $field, $value){
        return $query->where($field, 'LIKE', "%$value%");
}
```

So then you can use this method in such way:

```
User::like('name', 'Tomas')->get();
```

Comment: This is the more 'Laravel' way of doing this. It's just cleaner and allows you to adjust the scope in one place, instead of having to go around and adjust each `->where()`.

Comment: really love this answer. This make the model and its usage very elegant which is what laravel is about.

Answer (score 29):

FYI, the list of operators (containing **like** and all others) is in code:

```
/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php

protected $operators = array(
    '=', '<', '>', '<=', '>=', '<>', '!=',
    'like', 'not like', 'between', 'ilike',
    '&', '|', '^', '<<', '>>',
    'rlike', 'regexp', 'not regexp',
);
```

disclaimer:

Joel Larson's answer is correct.  Got my upvote.

I'm hoping this answer sheds more light on what's available via the Eloquent ORM (*points people in the right direct*).  Whilst a link to documentation would be **far** better, that link has proven itself elusive.

Answer (score 19):

Use double quotes instead of single quote eg :

```
where('customer.name', 'LIKE', "%$findcustomer%")
```

Below is my code:

```
public function searchCustomer($findcustomer)
{
    $customer = DB::table('customer')
                  ->where('customer.name', 'LIKE', "%$findcustomer%")
                  ->orWhere('customer.phone', 'LIKE', "%$findcustomer%")
                  ->get();

    return View::make("your view here");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you do not like double quotes like me, this will work for you with single quotes:

```
$value = Input::get('q');
$books = Book::where('name', 'LIKE', '%' . $value . '%')->limit(25)->get();

return view('pages/search/index', compact('books'));
```