# Laravel MySQL match against does not return results

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, match, match-against

Here is the controller :

```
public function getSearch()
{   
    $search = e(Input::get('name'));
    $search = preg_replace('#[^a-z A-Z 0-9 ? !]#i',' ', $search);
    $query = "MATCH (name,description) AGAINST ('".$search."' IN BOOLEAN MODE)";
    $accounts = Account::whereRaw($query)->paginate(10);
    if ($accounts->count())
    {
        return View::make('accounts.all')->with('accounts',$accounts);
    }
    else
    {
        $accounts = Account::paginate(10);
        Session::flash('fail', 'Sorry, the search term - '.$search.' did not match any records');
        return View::make('accounts.all')->with('accounts',$accounts);
    }
}
```

So the controller executes the else statement, however there are no any errors.

This is the row query:

```
SELECT * FROM `accounts`  WHERE MATCH(name,description) AGAINST('search word' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

Comment: show you dump of $accounts. `dd($accounts)`;

Comment: Hi , its solved I was trying to search using half of a word but I didn't know it needs to be the full word in order to be found, thanks

Answer (score 0):

its solved I was trying to search using half of a word but I didn't know it needs to be the full word in order to be found, thanks

Comment: even though you solved this you could just as well use something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13386774/using-eloquent-orm-in-laravel-to-perform-search-of-database-using-like)