# how to make an "like%" in a whereIn() eloquent Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent

I want to search within my user records those who have a phone that matches the array that I send, but I would like to use a "like%%", to independently search whether or not the phone has the "+52" example.
this is my code that only brings when the phone matches

```
        $directory= $request->phones;
        $new_arr = array_map('trim', explode(',', $directory));
        $users= USER::whereIn('phone', $new_arr)
          ->distinct()
          ->get();
```

Comment: This is an English forum, so please post in English

Comment: There is a Spanish page: https://es.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: Ojo. https://es.stackoverflow.com/ (pero tambien fijase esto: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30761950/laravel-5-like-equivalent-eloquent / https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13386774/using-eloquent-orm-in-laravel-to-perform-search-of-database-using-like

Comment: Dupe of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13386774/using-eloquent-orm-in-laravel-to-perform-search-of-database-using-like